# Multiple UIViewControllers - Best way to implement this

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm building an iOS application and I try to determine the best way to implement this :

I have a main UIViewController (MainViewController) that displays a simple view. This view contains a button that let the user add an object (let's say a Circle) to the main view. The user can add multiple circles by pressing the button and move each of them by dragging them. The circle objects should have their own color (randomly chosen).

The question is: what is the best way to implement this? 
Should I create an other UIViewController subclass (CircleViewController) for the Circle object, whose view actually draws the circle?
And then, when the user presses the button, should I create a new instance of this CircleViewController and add its view to the MainViewController?

When the user double-tap a circle, it should disappear... How can I send a message to the mainViewController to tell it to remove the concerned CircleViewController's view?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If your object is really as simple as a circle you should look at Quartz in Apple's Documentation and the method drawRect: in UIView.  If you are doing something more like an image you could subclass UIView and put your code in there.  Either way, you do not need to create new viewControllers.